# ASP.NET MembershipUserCollection sort by IsApproved, Comment

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to sort a MembershipUserCollection by IsApproved and then Comment without modifying the Stored Procedure?  Can Linq do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found another example that used the following code (I used a generic List instead of MembershipUserCollection):

```
users = users.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsApproved).OrderBy(x => x.Comment).ToList();
```

EDIT:
DOH!  Need ThenBy() instead of a second OrderBy():

```
users = users.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsApproved).ThenBy(x => x.Comment).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also this option to make it LINQ friendly before ordering.

```
IEnumerable<MembershipUser> members = sys.Membership.FindUsersByEmail(email).Cast<MembershipUser>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly--the MembershipUsersCollection isn't linq friendly. You can, however, pretty easily make it Linq friendly as Mike C. points out--just new up a `List<MembershipUser>` with your users.